# Bayesian Beta regression with random effects in R

Tags: r, bayesian, beta-regression

Does anyone know of an R package that does (Bayesian) Beta regression with random effects?

We know of `Bayesianbetareg` but this doesn't include random effects so I'm wondering if there is another package out there even if not on `CRAN` or if Bayesianbetareg can be coerced to include random effects. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

If sharing some data is useful, we're happy to upload it.

Comment: Not that I understand the descriptions but a quick search suggests it may be worth looking at the `brms` or `zoib` packages to see whether they do what you want

Comment: I have never used it for beta regression but `rstanarm::stan_glmer` can, according to the documentation, be used with `family=mgcv::betar`

Comment: Thank you both very much for your suggestions. I've never seen zoib before. We'll be able to dig into the documentation. It looks like brms is similar to rstanarm with a few speed improvements.